# Does cross-site AJAX queries use the same circuit established for the origin domain?

Tags: circuit, javascript

If, within the Tor Browser, I'm visiting `a.com`, and the loaded website does an AJAX query to b.com, will the AJAX query use the circuit established for `a.com`, or will the browser establish a new circuit for `b.com` and then do the AJAX query using that new circuit?

In case the first question is true, and I disable proxying 127.0.0.1 through Tor, and I visit my local server at 127.0.0.1, and the loaded localhost website does an AJAX query to b.com, will that AJAX query to b.com use my public IP?

NOTE: I'm not sure if by circuit I really mean route.

Answer (score 1):

first part: no, they will not be going separately, because the browser(a tweaked Firefox = Tor browser) can not know what to separate from what.

second part: it depends on the browser you're using. For true firefox use FoxyProxy add-on to route all the things properly